# Editing Image with Graphics in a Loop

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

I try to modify an image in a timer, but the image won't change. So this is how I initialize the image:

```
img = Image.FromFile(@"Resources\map.png");
```

And this is inside my timer:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
{
    g.TranslateTransform(-15, -15);
    foreach(Location l in locations)
    {
        g.DrawImage(color[l.getColor()], l.getPoint());
    }
}
BackgroundImage = img;
```

If I load the image from the file in my loop, it works just fine, but I'd really like to avoid it. Does anyone know how to solve this? I tried to use a Bitmap object for my background and draw the map on it in my timer, but it didn't work either.

edit:

I solved it like this now, but it still feels wrong, so is there a better way? I don't even understand why this is needed:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bg = new Bitmap(img)))
{
    g.TranslateTransform(-15, -15);
    foreach(Location l in locations)
    {
        g.DrawImage(color[l.getColor()], l.getPoint());
    }
}
BackgroundImage = bg;
```

Comment: What do you try here? An animation? Should the changes happen inside the loop? Or between Ticks? - Also: Repeatedly saying 'it works' or 'it doesn't work' are not  helpful problem descriptions! Explain what you want and what you get! - As it is the question is really unclear!

Comment: No animation and it doesn't matter. Changes happen inside the timer as I said. I mentioned, that it works when I reload the image from file every tick, otherwise it didn't. I found a solution where I don't need to reload from file every tick, but create a new Bitmap instance which is bad programming too and asked for a better solution. I honestly have no idea how I can clarify my intentions any better

Comment: OK, Adding a `Refresh()` after setting the `BackgroundImage` should help then. Make sure the Form has `DoubleBuffered` on.

Comment: If you still want help, please explain better what you are trying to do, and explain what you mean by "it doesn't work."  I can't tell whether you are trying to add new areas on each pass or whether you want to have a fixed background on which only new things will be drawn in each pass. `It doesn't work` could mean that you get an error, or a blank bitmap, or the same background image but your drawing was not preserved, or many other things. Your code certainly does what it is supposed to do *as written* -- if you want it to do something else you have to tell us what that is.

Comment: @Craig.Feied "I try to modify an image in a timer, but the image won't change." This is the very first sentence and as TaW was able to help, the question seems to be fine.